Formik value doesn't update to onsubmit
I have a counter in a Formik form. In the form, the user can increment a counter. I use setFieldValue to update the initial value of nbProducts, but when I submit the form nbProducts stays at 0. Here are the three components involved.
ProductCounter :
import { Field } from "formik"
import Image from "next/image"
import { useState } from "react"
import { Tooltip } from "../Tooltip/Tooltip"

const ProductCounter = ({ onCounterChange }) => {
  const [productCounter, setProductCounter] = useState<number>(0)

  const addProduct = () => {
    const updatedCounter = productCounter + 1
    setProductCounter(updatedCounter)
    onCounterChange(updatedCounter) // Appel de la fonction onCounterChange
  }

  const removeProduct = () => {
    if (productCounter > 0) {
      const updatedCounter = productCounter - 1

      setProductCounter(updatedCounter)
      onCounterChange(updatedCounter) // Appel de la fonction onCounterChange
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="mb-10">
        <div className="mb-2 mt-[10px] text-xl font-bold leading-normal lg:text-2xl">
          Nombre de produits éligibles<span className="text-red">*</span>
        </div>
        <p>
          1 produit Bonux éligible = 1 cadeau. Indique ici le nombre de produits Bonux éligibles figurant sur ta preuve
          d’achat.
        </p>
        <div className="mt-2 flex gap-2">
          <div className="flex w-1/3 items-center justify-center gap-1 rounded-[30px] border-2 border-blue px-3 text-xl font-bold">
            <button type="button" onClick={removeProduct} disabled={productCounter <= 0}>
              <Image src="/icons/icon-arrow.svg" width={30} height={30} alt="arrow" />
            </button>
            <Field as="div" name="nbProducts" type="number" value={productCounter}>
              {productCounter}
            </Field>
            <button type="button" onClick={addProduct}>
              <Image src="/icons/icon-arrow.svg" width={30} height={30} alt="arrow" className="rotate-180" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <Tooltip explainer="Ceci est une info-bulle" intent="primary" size="md" side="top" withArrow>
            <button className="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-blue text-white">
              <Image src="/icons/tooltip.svg" width={4} height={6} alt="?" className="m-auto" />
            </button>
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductCounter

Form:
import { Form, Formik, useFormik } from "formik"
import { validationSchema } from "./FormUtils"
import PersonalInfo from "./PersonalInfo"
import ProductCounter from "./ProductCounter"
import ShortForm, { ShortFormProps } from "./ShortForm"
// import UploadFile from "./UploadFiles"
import { Button } from "../Button/Button"
import { handleSubmit } from "@/app/api/improovApi"

const FullForm: React.FC<ShortFormProps> = ({
  checkedItemsData,
  setCheckedItemsData,
  cards,
  selectedCardId,
  handleCheckboxChange,
}) => (
  <div>
    <p className="mb-14 text-base text-red">* Champs obligatoires</p>
    <IssueForm
      checkedItemsData={checkedItemsData}
      setCheckedItemsData={setCheckedItemsData}
      cards={cards}
      selectedCardId={selectedCardId}
      handleCheckboxChange={handleCheckboxChange}
    />
  </div>
)

export default FullForm

interface IssueProps {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  email: string
  phone: string
  address: string
  postcode: string
  city: string
  nbProducts: number
  checked: boolean
  dotation: string
}
const IssueForm: React.FC<ShortFormProps> = ({
  checkedItemsData,
  setCheckedItemsData,
  cards,
  selectedCardId,
  handleCheckboxChange,
}) => {
  const InitialValues: IssueProps = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    address: "",
    postcode: "",
    city: "",
    nbProducts: 0,
    checked: false,
    dotation: "",
  }

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: InitialValues,
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: handleSubmit,
  })

  const handleCounterChange = (value: number) => {
    console.log("Nouvelle valeur du compteur :", value) // Ajout d'un console.log pour suivre les changements
    formik.setFieldValue("nbProducts", value)
    console.log("Valeur de nbProducts après mise à jour :", formik.values.nbProducts) // Ajout d'un console.log pour vérifier la valeur de nbProducts après mise à jour
  }

  console.log("Valeurs initiales du formulaire :", formik.values) // Ajout d'un console.log pour afficher les valeurs initiales du formulaire

  return (
    // Pass the useFormik() hook initial form values and a submit function that will
    // be called when the form is submitted
    <Formik initialValues={InitialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form>
        <PersonalInfo />
        <ProductCounter onCounterChange={handleCounterChange} />
        {/* <UploadFile /> */}

        <div className="mb-5">
          <ShortForm
            checkedItemsData={checkedItemsData}
            setCheckedItemsData={setCheckedItemsData}
            cards={cards}
            selectedCardId={selectedCardId}
            handleCheckboxChange={handleCheckboxChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-[25px] flex justify-center">
          <Button className="focus:shadow-green7 px-[15px]leading-none inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none">
            <button type="submit" className="uppercase">
              Je confirme
            </button>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  )
}

HandleSubmit:
import { FormikValues } from "formik"

// Fonction pour simuler une requête AJAX
const simulateFetch = (url: string, options: any) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open(options.method || "GET", url)

    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        const response = {
          ok: true,
          json: () => Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)),
        }
        resolve(response)
      } else {
        const error = new Error("Network response was not ok")
        reject(error)
      }
    }

    xhr.onerror = function () {
      const error = new Error("Network error occurred")
      reject(error)
    }

    if (options.headers) {
      Object.keys(options.headers).forEach((key) => {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(key, options.headers[key])
      })
    }
    xhr.send(options.body)
  })
}

// Fonction pour soumettre le formulaire
export const handleSubmit = async (values: FormikValues) => {
  try {
    const url = "https://app-preprod.improov-www02.evolix.eu/project/bonux/issue" // Mettre l'URL correcte ici
    const token = "OTLmCl5JA6CF" // Mettre le token correct ici
    if (!url || !token) {
      throw new Error("Missing URL or token")
    }

    console.log("Form values:", values) // Afficher les valeurs du formulaire dans la console

    const formData = new FormData()
    Object.entries(values).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      console.log("Appending to formData:", key, value) // Afficher chaque clé-valeur ajoutée à formData dans la console
      formData.append(key, String(value)) // Utiliser String() pour s'assurer que la valeur est de type string
    })

    // Envoi de la requête avec les données du formulaire
    const response = (await simulateFetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: { "X-Improov-Token": token },
    })) as Response

    // Traitement de la réponse
    const responseData = await response.json()
    console.log("Response from server:", responseData)
    alert("Form submitted successfully!") // Message de succès à supprimer après les tests
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error submitting form:", error)
    alert("Failed to submit form. Please try again later.")
  }
}

Where does that problem could come from?
Thank you
